# Calling blank arguments using enclosing functions

Tags: functions

Is there a way to call a function and have that function use an argument defined in an enclosing function?

e.g.,

```
set = Table@Range@50;

posE[set_] := Select[set, EvenQ]

tform1[mult_,set_] := (#*mult) & /@ set[[posE]];

t1set = tform1[10, set]
```

which leads to the following message/error,

> Part::pspec: Part specification posE is neither an integer nor a list
>   of integers. >>

I would like `posE` to get its argument `set_` from the second argument in `tform1` (also named `set_`).

Is this possible? is there a better way to do this?

(Note that I do not want to combine the two functions into a single function).

Comment: how about: `Cases[set, x_?EvenQ :> 10 x]`? (without knowing what you actually want to achieve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined a function `posE[set]` but when you call it, it has no argument. You must call it with an argument. So change the function definition to

```
 tform1[mult_,set_] := (#*mult) & /@ set[[posE[set]]];
```

If what you are really after is a list that goes from 20 to 500 by 20s (which is what this code seems to do) then there is much better way to do it.

```
Range[20, 500, 20]
```

Comment: No, I was just using these functions as an example. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

is it too early to add an answer to my own question?

I just found a way to do it using `With`:

```
tform1[mult_, set_, pos_] := 
  With[{posf = pos[set]}, (#*mult) & /@ set[[posf]]];

t1set = tform1[10, set, posE]
```

This works very similar to @bill s' answer.

Comment: You could eliminate the `With` and just use `tform1[mult_, set_, pos_] := (#*mult) & /@ set[[pos[set]]]` as per Bill s answer.